# Set cookie in PHP from a getJSON call on two different servers

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, setcookie

I have two servers, 'www.domain.local' and 'api.domain.local'. I want to set a cookie in a script on the api server that is called from the www. Chrome does not let me do that (didn't try other browsers yet)

my PHP code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
echo json_encode(array("cookie"=>print_r($_COOKIE,true)));
setcookie("test","ok",time()+24000*3600,"/",".domain.local");
```

in my jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.domain.local/test.php",{
  command:"setcookie"
},function(fb){
  alert(fb.cookie);
});
```

The PHP is first returning the cookies it has, the first run this should be zero, and it is. In the header of the PHP script I see the following:

> Set-Cookie:test=ok; expires=Tue, 27-Oct-2015 22:52:52 GMT; path=/; domain=.domain.local X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.14

Which is what I expect. But the cookie isn't set. When I run the jQuery again I am expecting the cookie to be set (get an alert with the print_r of $_COOKIE), but I get nothing. One thing I noticed in the 'cookies' tab of the network resources in the debug part of Chrome is that the expiry was set as "Invalid Date". If I run the PHP script directly I don't have this problem though.

Is it possible to set a cookie in a PHP script called from jQuery and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see, set a cookie on a different domain to the one that the page is loading on and in PHP from jQuery

Someone might post how you're supposed to do it.
I might just cheat.

**www.domain.local/test.html** includes

```
$.getScript("http://api.domain.local/test.php?dowhat=setcookie");
```

**api.domain.local/test.php** is

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['dowhat']){
    case 'showcookie':
        print_r($_COOKIE);
        break;
    case 'setcookie':
        setcookie("test",date('Y m D H:i:s'),time()+24000*3600,"/");
        break;
}
header("Content-type: application/javascript"); // may as well, it expects this
die;
```

Now go to http://api.domain.local/test.php?dowhat=showcookie

```
Array ([test] => 2013 01 Thu 00:20:52 )
```

Ta-da!

P.S. I wouldn't advise doing it this simply if you need it to be set without someone naughty being able to cheat too.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit weird though that the PHP script is able to get the cookie when the call is a $.getScript, but not on a $.post or $.getJSON...

Comment: It's not weird, you're tricking the browser into executing PHP on another server. You can load JS from any source, there's no security check. Except we're not loading it, we're just pretending. $.post should also be fine.  $.getJSON needs xbrowser trickery.

Comment: With a $.post or $.getJSON to/from a PHP script you're also executing PHP on another server, right? What I saw in the debug was that a cookie was set, but the date was wrong. It wasn't. Changing the getJSON to getScript fixed it, so the date was right. Security would make sense in a way, though I would think the server running PHP is setting the cookie, not the server that posts the information there. Or could this be a Chrome weirdness?

Comment: When you're using $.getJSON the security between domains isn't set up correctly or at all so the browser is not letting it happen.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your code. On the first line you forgot to close your string with `"`.